# What should the name of our main chatroom be called?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, chat

Every Stack Exchange site (Not all) main chatroom has a unique name that is related to the main site itself.

for Example:

- SuperUser: Root Acess
- Gaming: The Bridge
- IOT: Chat of Things
- Unix & Linux: /dev/chat

and etc

What should our main chat room be named?

[The Real Essential Questions of Every Beta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/223675/311917)

> 5. Whats an interesting name for the chat room?
>      Every site comes with its official chat room. This is created automatically and can be reached from the Site Switcher on the top left. The chat room is the third place of your community, after main and meta. It is like the lounge where everybody can get together to discuss, complain and have fun. Personalizing this space to reflect your community and what you are, is one of the small steps to take towards building an active and engaged community.
>      Try to get a few ideas up, discuss and vote on them. The name could be something esoteric in your field, or something that every person may understand. Whichever it may be, go ahead and start the discussion!

Answer (score 14):

I think we can all agree:

ChatOps :)

Comment: The idea is fun, but I feel it's omitting the Dev part of the community.

Comment: How about DevSecChatOps just to be inclusive :P

Comment: Start to be long :p

Comment: @DaveSwersky 

ChatOps is good one. :)

What about DeployChats?

Comment: I personally like "ChatOps" because it is a real thing in DevOps- a common chat room in which one can execute real commands on servers (e.g. Slack.)  Companies that practice ChatOps use it for communication between Dev, Ops, and many other groups.  One man's opinion :)

Comment: Seem community consensus is for this name, I'll rename the Chat Room

Answer (score 6):

Just in case, I feel DevOps is already a good name.

Unsure we should change it in fact.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe we can go another route and name it `ContinuousChat`?

Answer (score 3):

`DevOpsChat` or `DevOpsTalk`(s)?

You can tell I'm a dev, can't you? ;)

Answer (score 1):

How about `MessageBus` or something similar?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest `BOFH` -- short for Bastard Operator from Hell.  The [BOFH series](https://www.theregister.co.uk/data_centre/bofh/) has been a favorite for sysadmins for [eons](http://users.bestweb.net/%7Ebofh/).  While it can probably offend everybody at some point it also seems healthier to me than crying in our beers.

> "Huh? I'd used 4 Meg already, How could I have 4 Meg Available?"
>
> I say nothing. It'll come to him.

They quibbled over **MEGAbytes**!

P.S.: I realize this is a bit late of an answer, but since none of the others have stuck there's still hope. :)

Comment: Sounds too OP only oriented and likely to start debate about offensive name. (Despite I like the idea of not crying in the beers)

Answer (score 0):

I may be out of synch a bit, but how about [***UserFriendly***](http://www.userfriendly.org)?
Can't not have some humour in there...

Comment: Strictly personnal position,  I do like it :)